# What is the number of 1's at even and odd places of a number in binary representation?

Tags: c++, performance, binary, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

Is their is any faster way to implement it whether it is bitwise or any function for an integer in the range of 64-bit.Except the one I've implemented.

```
/* 
Find F(i)=abs(a(i)-b(i))
a(i)=number of 1's in even position 
b(i)=number of 1's in odd position 
for an integer i, where i fits in 64-bit
*/
//function calculate the above equation
//returns the answer
long long int F(long long int k)
{
    //size of array is taken for 64-bit number
    int a[64]={0},i,a,b;
    long long int m;
    m=k;
    //convert long long int into binary 
    for(i=63;i>-1;i--)
    {
        if(m==1||m==0)
        {
            a[i]=m;
            break;       //exit the for loop
        }
        a[i]=m%2;        //storing bit by bit
        m/=2;           
    }
    // initialized with a value of zero
    a=0;
    b=0;
    //find first bit having 1
    int f;
    for(i=0;i<64;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==1)
        {
            f=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    //calculating the number of 1's in even and odd positions
    for(i=f;i<64;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==1)
        {
            if((63-f)%2==0)
            {
                a++;          //1's in even positions
            }
            else
            {
                b++;          //1's in odd positions
            }
        }
    }

    //return the answer
    return abs(a-b);
}
```

So basically what I am trying to do is to convert the integer in its binary representation by simple method of using mod 2. Then a task is performed to find the first 1 in its binary representation for left to right and our pointer is on the first number. Now count the number of 1's in odd and even position using the index of first 1.Finally return the absolute difference of total even and odd place 1's.

Comment: A site for you: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: For fast implementation use binary shift operation.

Comment: @Learner: That's a bit faster (maybe), but the bithacks page still lists far better options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way:

```
#include <stdint.h>
int absdiffevenoddpopcount(uint64_t x) {
    uint64_t a = x &  0x5555555555555555;
    uint64_t b = x & ~0x5555555555555555;
    while(a && b) {
        a &= a - 1;
        b &= b - 1;
    }
    x = a ? a : b;
    int r = 0;
    while(x) {
        x &= x - 1;
        r++;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Anyway, this page collects such bit-hacks: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Also, some processors have special instructions which might be faster for (bit-)population-counting, often compilers provide it to C as a builtin.

Comment: Where do those 666 masks come from?

Comment: @harold: Wrong mask, sry.

Comment: Note that for performance it may be better to use a builtin popcount, since it may map to one CPU instruction. For instance on Intel there is such an instruction since Nehalem.

Comment: @Deduplicator I saw just your original code. Didn't see the edit. But yes you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you can do is use & to leave only the odd and the even bits.
The you can popcount both numbers, and finally return the difference.
So:

```
long long int F(long long int k)
{
     long long int odds, evens;
     odds = k & 0x5555555555555555;
     evens = k & 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa;
     return abs( __builtin_popcountll(odds) -  __builtin_popcountll(evens));
}
```

I wrote it using gcc bultin popcount. If use another compiler you can find this in its manual.

Comment: Why are you widening the result to `long long`?  popcount returns `int`, which has plenty of range for even enormous `long long`.

Comment: I took his original function signature, maybe he needs it to be long long for something else.

Answer (score 1):

A more C++ friendly version:

```
int F(long long const k) {
  return std::abs(static_cast<int>(std::bitset<64>(k & 0x5555555555555555).count()) - 
                  static_cast<int>(std::bitset<64>(k & 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa).count()));
}
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca235411937cfc8c)